# Random freezes (including during attempted install)

Tags: server, system-installation, freeze

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 Server on an Intel NUC (NUC8i3BEK). It has a 256GB SSD and 8GB (2x 4GB) of RAM. I have just updated the BIOS (today) to the latest version (0081).

It has previously been running 20.04 (upgraded from 18.04), but I wanted to do a clean install to clean it up and configure a few things differently. I had been running into a strange issue where it would drop off the network after 24 hours (I suspect related to DHCP renewal) and figured it would fix that too. Most recently, it started freezing during boot, but with no obvious error message.

I have downloaded the AMD64 version of Ubuntu Server 20.04 (ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso). I have confirmed the MD5 is correct.

When I try to install it, the installer freezes. It freezes at a slightly different point each time - sometimes it doesn't even reach the key generation, other times I can select the language and make it to the next screen before it freezes. Once it freezes, the keyboard is completely unresponsive (even to Ctrl + Alt + Delete) and I have to power cycle the machine.

Things I've tried:

- Writing the image using Etcher (on Mac)
- Writing the image using Rufus (on Windows) in both ISO and DD modes
- Switching UEFI boot on and off
- Two different USB drives

I have the same issue with the Ubuntu 18.04 installer, however I have managed to install Ubuntu 16.04. After a few minutes however, it also froze and crashed.

That last part is what's confusing me - now it seems like a hardware issue. I'm running MemTest86 (V8.4 Free) right now, but so far no errors (Pass 1/4 complete).

I'm kind of at a loss right now - any ideas how / where to go from here? To throw in a curve ball, I only really have WiFi access and connecting via Ethernet cable would be a huge pain.

---

EDIT:

Since posting, I have been through the Intel debugging list. I have tried a different power supply, removing / swapping memory modules, removing the SSD and resetting BIOS options. No change.

I now have a reproducible use case - the Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop edition. I can boot into the "Try Ubuntu" mode and it lasts about 15-30 seconds before hanging. It never recovers and I have to power cycle manually.

Intel support is claiming they can't help since Ubuntu is not a supported OS. I'm going to see if I can download the Windows 10 installer and reproduce the issue, but it's tough on our slow connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE

After downloading the Windows 10 ISO, I found the exact same behavior occurred during Windows 10 setup - it hung a few minutes after booting.

Intel are replacing it under warranty (it was purchased in December 2018).

In case anyone else stumbles across this, my advice is the following:

- Test all user-installed hardware issues - remove / swap / test memory, HDD, etc
- Test the power supply (try a new power adapter)
- Test the software - try a different OS, live CD, etc

Once you've tested and passed all of those, contact Intel for a warranty claim. I was able to explain what I had tested and they were able to commence the warranty process.